# How would i be able to read and write files of different extensions c# and display them

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, stream

I'm currently using stream reader and writer to read and write the files onto the webpage. Currently .html files are working but .jpg and images of any sorts do not post.

How would I be able to be able to serve up file like the mimetype mappings?

```
namespace wdd_assign_07_github
{
    class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //TcpListener server = null;

            if (args == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("args is null");

            }
            else if (args.Length != 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not enough arguments");
            }
            else
            {
                //do nothing
            }

            string webRoot = args[0].Substring(args[0].LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
            string webIP = args[1].Substring(args[1].LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
            string webPort = args[2].Substring(args[2].LastIndexOf("=") + 1);
            int numWebPort = Int32.Parse(webPort);
            Int32 port = numWebPort;

            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(port);
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                //performing a blocking vall to accept requests
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection");
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

                try
                {
                    //client makes a request
                    //lets handle that request
                    string request = sr.ReadLine();

                    //lets print that out on our server console
                    Console.WriteLine(request);

                    //lets split that request
                    //[0]GET [1]PAGE [2]HTTPstring
                    string[] tokens = request.Split(' ');
                    string page = tokens[1];

                    //lets check if they requested the dedault page or not
                    if (page == "/")
                    {
                        page = "<H1>This is the default page</H1>";
                    }

                    //lets find the file now
                    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(webRoot + page);
                    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n");

                    //lets send the file
                    string data = file.ReadLine();

                    //while data doesnt equal null
                    while (data != null)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(data);
                        sw.Flush();
                        data = file.ReadLine();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //error
                    sw.WriteLine("HTTP/1.0 404 OK\n");
                    sw.WriteLine("<H1>SORRY! We couldnt find your file</H1>");
                    sw.Flush();
                }

                client.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things you should consider:

- Include [`Content-Type`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.5%5D) and
  [`Content-Length`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2)
  headers.
- Use dictionary to define content types

```cs
var mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
    {".html", "text/html"},
    {".js", "application/javascript"},
    // ...
};

// later in your method
var ext = Path.GetExtension(page);
var contentType = mappings[ext]; // may throw if mapping is missing
```

- To use [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.8) instead of `StreamReader` (at least for binary files like jpg and png)

Comment: BTW thank you so much for the reply, the dictionary method seems like a great idea :)

Comment: @Mamooji: `StreamReader` is for reading text files. Even HTML, JavaScript and others are text files, you don't really care, you are just copying bytes into the output stream. So `FileStream` will work for everything.

Comment: BTW @Mamooji, You will thank me by upvoting my answer. 